# cannot borrow `c` as mutable more than once at a time (again)

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement [the 3rd bullet point from chapter 8.3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#summary), with a difference that an employee can be added to multiple departments.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod company {
    use std::collections::HashMap;

    struct Company<'a> {
        employees: HashMap<String, Employee>,
        departments: HashMap<String, Department<'a>>,
    }

    struct Department<'a> {
        name: String,
        employees: HashMap<&'a str, &'a Employee>,
    }

    struct Employee {
        name: String,
    }

    impl<'a> Company<'a> {
        pub fn new() -> Company<'a> {
            Company {
                employees: HashMap::new(),
                departments: HashMap::new(),
            }
        }

        pub fn add_employee_to_department(&'a mut self, employee: &str, department: &str) {
            let d = self.departments.entry(String::from(department)).or_insert(Department::new(department));
            let e = self.employees.entry(String::from(employee)).or_insert(Employee::new(employee));
            d.employees.entry(&e.name).or_insert(e);
        }
    }

    impl<'a> Department<'a> {
        pub fn new(name: &str) -> Department<'a> {
            Department {
                name: String::from(name),
                employees: HashMap::new(),
            }
        }
    }

    impl Employee {
        fn new(name: &str) -> Employee {
            Employee {
                name: String::from(name),
            }
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_add_employee_to_department() {
        let mut c = Company::new();
        c.add_employee_to_department("Sally", "Sales");
        c.add_employee_to_department("Jim", "Sales");
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get an error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `c` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/company.rs:55:9
   |
54 |         c.add_employee_to_department("Sally", "Sales");
   |         ---------------------------------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
55 |         c.add_employee_to_department("Jim", "Sales");
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         second mutable borrow occurs here
   |         first borrow later used here
```

If I remove lifetime `'a` from `add_employee_to_department`

```rust
        pub fn add_employee_to_department(&mut self, employee: &str, department: &str) {
            let d = self.departments.entry(String::from(department)).or_insert(Department::new(department));
            let e = self.employees.entry(String::from(employee)).or_insert(Employee::new(employee));
            d.employees.entry(&e.name).or_insert(e);
        }
```

I get a different error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/company.rs:29:36
   |
29 |             let e = self.employees.entry(String::from(employee)).or_insert(Employee::new(employee));
   |                                    ^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/company.rs:27:43
   |
27 |         pub fn add_employee_to_department(&mut self, employee: &str, department: &str) {
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/company.rs:29:21
   |
29 |             let e = self.employees.entry(String::from(employee)).or_insert(Employee::new(employee));
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/company.rs:19:10
   |
19 |     impl<'a> Company<'a> {
   |          ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/company.rs:30:50
   |
30 |             d.employees.entry(&e.name).or_insert(e);
   |                                                  ^
```

And if I comment the last line in `add_employee_to_department`

```rust
        pub fn add_employee_to_department(&mut self, employee: &str, department: &str) {
            let d = self.departments.entry(String::from(department)).or_insert(Department::new(department));
            let e = self.employees.entry(String::from(employee)).or_insert(Employee::new(employee));
            //d.employees.entry(&e.name).or_insert(e);
        }
```

the code compiles and the test runs.

I'm new to Rust and could be wrong here, but it seems the original error (`cannot borrow 'c' as mutable more than once at a time`) is a bug in the borrow checker when a lifetime used with the first `&'a self` parameter.

A simpler test shows the same problem.  The code below compiles as is, but if I add lifetime `'a` to `fn update(&'a mut self, value: &'a T)`, I get the same error: `Cannot borrow 'w' as mutable more than once at a time`.

Any advise on what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated!

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod wrapper {
    struct Wrapper<'a, T> {
        value: &'a T,
    }

    impl<'a, T> Wrapper<'a, T> {
        fn new(value: &T) -> Wrapper<T> {
            Wrapper {
                value,
            }
        }

        fn value(&self) -> &T {
            self.value
        }

        fn update(&mut self, value: &'a T) {
            self.value = value;
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_wrapper() {
        let mut w = Wrapper::new(&12);
        w.update(&14);
        w.update(&16);
        assert_eq!(w.value(), &16);
    }
}
```

Comment: For one `&'a mut Type<'a>` ties a knot with the lifetime constraint solver that causes the borrow to last for the entire life of the object, disallowing other references to be made. And then removing `'a` from the method yields another lifetime error which is because you're trying to make a self-referential struct (`departments.employees` trying to reference `employees` in the same `Company` object). See [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/2189130)

Comment: Thank you @kmdreko!  Errors in both cases, `&mut self` and `&'a mut self`, make sense now.